# Why do people define their own offsetof?

Tags: c, portability

Having just seen [What does the following macro do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453063/what-does-the-following-macro-do) I gotta ask my own question: why do so many applications' headers define `offsetof` themselves?  Is there some reason why `<stddef.h>` is not to be relied upon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it's that they distrust the standard `offsetof` -- at least from what I've seen, it's usually that they're just unaware of it.

Comment: It's sort of sad how plausible this is.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there some reason why  is not to be relied upon?

I know one of the reasons. GCC produces a warning when standard offsetof() is used on fields of C++ classes. That leads some people to roll out their own version which doesn't trigger the warning.

Comment: Terrible idea. Warnings are there for a reason...That's like saying "Oh, undefined behavior? I spit on you...by the way why is my program non-portable and crashing?"

Comment: Which is dumb, because that warning is there for good reasons.

Comment: Yes. Especially on one of the projects I worked they actually were mixing polymorphism/multiple inheritance and the offsetof() and there were memory corruption because of that and it took me forever to explain the people why it couldn't work and why there is a warning for it.

Comment: This is the programming equivalent of burying your head in the sand in hopes that you won't been seen and devoured.

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe it's legacy code from a C compiler that wasn't ANSI compliant and didn't have `offsetof`?

Comment: I'd believe this except it seems like all that code should have died out by now.  Maybe people have been cargo-culting it from each other ever since because they don't know about stddef.h, like Jerry suggests.

Comment: @Zack: I'd easily believe that people have been cargo culting it.  There are a lot of misconceptions that `offsetof` wasn't standardized until C99 too.